# How to map VK_DECIMAL to my own character

Tags: c#, winforms, mapping, keycode

I would like to see a '*' (or any custom character) whenever a person presses the numpad decimal key (i.e. the '.' or ',' key on the numpad)

My current attempt is:

```
private bool numpadDecimal;

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (numpadDecimal)
        e.KeyChar = customNumpadDecimalCharacter;
}

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    numpadDecimal = (e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal);
}
```

This works in general, but I would prefer a more straightforward approach. Any ideas?

Edit: I think it is a mapping problem (KeyCode => Char). So I wonder whether I can override the windows mapping somehow.

Comment: Whats not straightforward with your current approach?

Comment: Good question. I will clarify in my post.

Comment: Do you want to have this behavior in your application or globally in windows?

Comment: If there is an application wide solution, I would be happy to hear about

Comment: You can have a low-level hook to listen to keystrokes globally, intercept them, cancel them and simulate a press of a different key. What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: The reason behind it is to ensure that the numeric decimal is mapped to the decimal separator char. This is not always the case as some customers change the keyboard layout. However, they insist on getting the decimal separator when hitting the numpad decimal key.

Comment: But I don't suppose they want it mapped in FireFox as well, right? Probably in a specific application - yours(?) - to which I think your solution is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. I'll trust your judgement and will have more confidence in my own solutions in the future.